# CSS vw but in percentage of containing block width?

Tags: css

Yesterday I wanted to have a div that keeps its size ratio and I found (or I was dreaming) that a CSS unit represented 1% of the containing block width. I tested and it worked.
I thought it was `vb` but it is not.

I searched everywhere but this unit doesn't seem to exist, am I crazy ?

Comment: Never heard about it. Maybe wrong language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [**Draft CSS Level 4**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#viewport-relative-lengths) which adds the `vi`, `vb`, `ic`, `lh`, and `rlh` length units

> `vi` unit
>
> Equal to 1% of the size of the initial containing block in the direction of the root element’s inline axis.
>
> `vb` unit
>
> Equal to 1% of the size of the initial containing block in the direction of the root element’s block axis.

More at the Spec (linked above) or [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

### At present these is NO browser support for these new usits.

Comment: Note that the first part of the question asks about percentage width of the containing block of a div, not of the *initial* containing block, which would only be the same thing in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_vb 2022-11-21: Chrome/Safari support, not edge yet